# PySimpleGUI actualizar texto de un label

Tags: python, interfaz-gráfica

estoy intentando hacer un loading. Lo que necesito es simular el tiempo de carga de una partida.

Este es el código que tengo

```
img_logo = os.path.join('media', 'scrabbleArLogo.png')
contenido = [[sg.Image(img_logo, background_color='#4f280a')],
            [sg.Text(font=('Arial',20),size=(20,10),justification='center',background_color='#4f280a',text_color = 'yellow',key='texto')] 
            ]
v = sg.Window('Loading',layout=contenido,size=(400,400), background_color='#4f280a',element_justification='center', keep_on_top=True, grab_anywhere=True)
v.finalize()
texto = ['Chequeando imágenes de fichas','Chequeando imágenes de casilleros especiales','Chequeando imágenes de avatares']
while True: 
    event, values = v.read(timeout=100)        
    v['texto'].update(texto[0])
    time.sleep(1)
    v['texto'].update(texto[2])
v.close()
```

De todas las formas que intenté (con un for recorriendo el largo del texto y actualizando texto[i], actualizando manualmente como ahí, etc), sólo hace la última actualización. En ese caso no sale nunca,pero con un break sí.
Necesito que aparezca en pantalla un texto, espere un tiempo, actualice a otro y así hasta terminar y salir (después engarza con otra parte del programa)

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto

```
texto = ['Chequeando imágenes de fichas','Chequeando imágenes de casilleros especiales','Chequeando imágenes de avatares']
i=0
while True: 
    event, values = v.read(timeout=100) 
    chequeos()
    if i < len(texto):
       v['texto'].update('{}'.format(texto[i]))
       time.sleep(2)   
       i += 1
    else: 
       break
            
 v.close()
```